# How do I update my version of Django?

Tags: python, django

I currently have it installed and it's running a website.

http://www.djangoproject.com/download/
This is the new version. How do I upgrade it? (How do I install the new version over my current one?)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

read about this in :

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/install/

#### For installing Django to be able to update to the latest code in trunk:

> If you'd like to be able to update
>   your Django code occasionally with the
>   latest bug fixes and improvements,
>   follow these instructions:
>
> 1.Make sure that you have Subversion installed, and that you can run its
>   commands from a shell. (Enter svn help
>   at a shell prompt to test this.)
>
> 2.Check out Django's main development branch (the 'trunk') like so:
>
> svn co
>   http://code.djangoproject.com/svn/django/trunk/
>   django-trunk
>   3.Next, make sure that the Python interpreter can load Django's code.
>   There are various ways of
>   accomplishing this. One of the most
>   convenient, on Linux, Mac OSX or other
>   Unix-like systems, is to use a
>   symbolic link:
>
> ln -s `pwd`/django-trunk/django
>   SITE-PACKAGES-DIR/django (In the above
>   line, change SITE-PACKAGES-DIR to
>   match the location of your system's
>   site-packages directory, as explained
>   in the "Where are my site-packages
>   stored?" section above.)
>
> Alternatively, you can define your
>   PYTHONPATH environment variable so
>   that it includes the django-trunk
>   directory. This is perhaps the most
>   convenient solution on Windows
>   systems, which don't support symbolic
>   links. (Environment variables can be
>   defined on Windows systems from the
>   Control Panel.)
>
> What about Apache and mod_python?
>
> If you take the approach of setting
>   PYTHONPATH, you'll need to remember to
>   do the same thing in your Apache
>   configuration once you deploy your
>   production site. Do this by setting
>   PythonPath in your Apache
>   configuration file.
>
> More information about deployment is
>   available, of course, in our How to
>   use Django with mod_python
>   documentation.
>
> 4.On Unix-like systems, create a symbolic link to the file
>   django-trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py
>   in a directory on your system path,
>   such as /usr/local/bin. For example:
>
> ln -s
>   `pwd`/django-trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py
>   /usr/local/bin This simply lets you
>   type django-admin.py from within any
>   directory, rather than having to
>   qualify the command with the full path
>   to the file.
>
> On Windows systems, the same result
>   can be achieved by copying the file
>   django-trunk/django/bin/django-admin.py
>   to somewhere on your system path, for
>   example C:\Python24\Scripts.
>
> You don't have to run python setup.py
>   install, because you've already
>   carried out the equivalent actions in
>   steps 3 and 4.
>
> When you want to update your copy of
>   the Django source code, just run the
>   command svn update from within the
>   django-trunk directory. When you do
>   this, Subversion will automatically
>   download any changes

#### For updating Django from stable release to another stable release:

> If you are upgrading your installation of Django from a previous
>   version, you will need to uninstall the old Django version before
>   installing the new version.
>
> If you installed Django using setup.py install, uninstalling is as
>   simple as deleting the django directory from your Python
>   site-packages.
>
> If you installed Django from a Python egg, remove the Django .egg
>   file, and remove the reference to the egg in the file named
>   easy-install.pth. This file should also be located in your
>   site-packages directory.

Answer (score 5):

First of all, don't. Install/upgrade it on your staging server first and test your app to make sure that it still works. Only after complete testing should you cut over to the new version on your production website.